# Angular 7 - window.open with app path - Blocking?

Tags: angular, window.open

I need to use window.open for a functionality that allows to open an Angular route in a new tab.
I'm noticing using it tends to block the code in the parent window until the new window has finished loading. I find that a bit odd and annoying.

If I open an external URL no such thing happens.

Any idea what I need to do?

Thanks

Comment: can you try to build prod and check the same

Comment: @RezaRahmati Wow, thanks for the hint. That doesn't happen in prod. Do you know why?

Comment: You're welcome, it was a random guess by experince ;)

Comment: @RezaRahmati I'd love to know why it's doing it :)

Comment: yeah, me too, this is why I didn't post it as answer

Comment: @RezaRahmati Well thanks. I won't question it :) As long as it works in prod, I'm good for now.